# ScrollView IBOutlet nil when using protocol to call function in viewDidDisappear

Tags: swift, scrollview, protocols, iboutlet

I have a scrollView that contains a dynamic amount of WeatherViewControllers each displaying the weather data of a different city the user has saved. The user can segue from the WeatherViewControllers to a CityListViewController. Where they can add and remove cities from their list which in turn should add and remove WeatherViewControllers from the scrollView upon dismissing the CityListViewController, this is where I am running into a problem.

**Currently I am trying to use a protocol in to call the func reloadScrollView which calls viewDidLoad in the scrollViewController upon dismissing(viewDidDisappear) the CityListViewController but am getting an error:**

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file
```

when it gets to:

```
totalScrollView.addSubview(weatherScreen.view)
```

Using debugger I have found that totalScrollView is nil and that is causing the problem. Is there a way to make the scrollView load so it is not nil when dismissing the other viewController

OR

is the a better time to call use this protocol to call this function?

Side Note: Upon initially opening the app the scrollView loads properly with all the correct WeatherViewControllers in the UIScrollView and the correct cities in the list.

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController, ScrollReloadProtocol {

func reloadScrollView() {

    print("SCROLL RELOADED!!!!!*******")
    self.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBOutlet var totalScrollView: UIScrollView!
var pages = [ViewController]()
var x = 0
var weatherScreensArray = [SavedCityEntity]()
var weatherScreenStringArray = [String]()
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
var horizString = "H:|[page1(==view)]"

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //userDefaults used to keep track of which screen is which to put different cities on different viewControllers
    defaults.set(0, forKey: "screenNumber")
    //load cities to get number of cities saved
    loadCities()

    var views : [String: UIView] = ["view": view]
    //create all weatherWeatherControllers
    while x <= weatherScreensArray.count {

        pages.append(createAndAddWeatherScreen(number: x))
        weatherScreenStringArray.append("page\(x+1)")
        views["\(weatherScreenStringArray[x])"] = pages[x].view
        let addToHoriz = "[\(weatherScreenStringArray[x])(==view)]"
        horizString.append(addToHoriz)

        x+=1
    }

    horizString.append("|")

    let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[page1(==view)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: horizString, options: [.alignAllTop, .alignAllBottom], metrics: nil, views: views)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalConstraints + horizontalConstraints)
}

//Function to create and add weatherViewController
func createAndAddWeatherScreen(number: Int) -> ViewController {

        defaults.set(number, forKey: "screenNumber")

      let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let weatherScreen = story.instantiateViewController(identifier: "View Controller") as! ViewController


        weatherScreen.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        totalScrollView.addSubview(weatherScreen.view)

        addChild(weatherScreen)
        weatherScreen.didMove(toParent: self)

    return weatherScreen
}
```

}

Comment: Man! Your approach is really bad.

Comment: haha, I'm still learning. Could you explain a better way for me to do this?

Comment: Of course! Can you please explain me the whole scenario- what do you want to do?

Comment: Well I making a weather app (for learning purposes). Similar to the default app on the iphone. 

I had the weatherViewController and cityListControllers working. Now I am adding the feature to swipe back and forth between the different weatherViewControllers to see the weather in different cities you have saved and to do this I am using the scrollViewController. (I think adding this at the end made it more difficult plus I have never tried to implement anything like this)

So now I want the scrollview to dynamically add another weatherView if the user adds one at the cityListController

Comment: So right now I am trying to do this by reloading the scrollViewController upon dismissing the CityListController, but am running into the issue where the IBOutlets are still nil upon running the protocol

Answer (score 0):

Skipping that fact that your are not doing it right, let's forcus on the one issue at a time. You are trying to access the `totalScrollView` implicitly in the `viewDidLoad` where if the outlet is linked it should be loaded at that point. If it is `nil` you should:

1. Make sure that you have the `.storyboard` or `.xib` file defining the `ScrollViewController` layout.
2. Make sure you are loading this controller from that storyboard/xib.
3. Make sure that the view controller in the storyboard/xib file has set its class to `ScrollViewController`, similar to the following print screen:
   [image]
4. Make sure that the outlet is linked in the storyboard/xib to this property in your code file (probably `ScrollViewController.swift`). If not:

   - open storyboard and sorucecode file in separate editors
   - drag and drop from the dot on the left of the property declaration to the UIScrollView in the storyboard
     [image]
   - make sure that there is added a link to `Referencing Outlets`
     [image]